# sending emails from cron tasks in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, email, cron, swiftmailer

I am trying to send emails using cron tasks with Symfony , so my question is how would I execute my command with using swiftmailer in my execute function ?Thanks in advance

I want the swiftmailer to be in my execute method,  so I can send emails based on cron tasks

```
                    $mail = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
                    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com')
                         ->setTo('to@example.com')
                         ->setSubject('Email subject')
                         ->setBody('email body, can be swift template')

                    $this->get('mailer')->send($mail);
```

my CronTasksRunCommand

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $output->writeln('<comment>Running Cron Tasks...</comment>');

    $this->output = $output;
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $crontasks = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:CronTask')->findAll();

    foreach ($crontasks as $crontask) {
        // Get the last run time of this task, and calculate when it should run next
        $lastrun = $crontask->getLastRun() ? $crontask->getLastRun()->format('U') : 0;
        $nextrun = $lastrun + $crontask->getInterval();

        // We must run this task if:
        // * time() is larger or equal to $nextrun
        $run = (time() >= $nextrun);

        if ($run) {
            $output->writeln(sprintf('Running Cron Task <info>%s</info>', $crontask));

            // Set $lastrun for this crontask
            $crontask->setLastRun(new \DateTime());

            try {
                $commands = $crontask->getCommands();
                foreach ($commands as $command) {
                    $output->writeln(sprintf('Executing command <comment>%s</comment>...', $command));

                    // Run the command
                    $this->runCommand($command);
                }

                $output->writeln('<info>SUCCESS</info>');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $output->writeln('<error>ERROR</error>');
            }

            // Persist crontask
            $em->persist($crontask);
        } else {
            $output->writeln(sprintf('Skipping Cron Task <info>%s</info>', $crontask));
        }
    }

    // Flush database changes
    $em->flush();

    $output->writeln('<comment>Done!</comment>');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Command class extends ContainerAwareCommand class, then just replace

```
$this->get('mailer')->send($mail);
```

with

```
$this->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($mail);
```